# How to use *ngFor on a JSON data in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a dymanic table with rows and columns defined as a array and JSON object. I am able to build the column headers dynamically. But the rows are not getting rendered. I am coming from angularjs 1.x background and new to angular.

Please help we understand the problem. Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/BG22Z1videTlzU3SrjcT?p=preview

```
<table class="table">  
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
                        {{column}}
                    </th>                       
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr *ngFor="let userDate of userDateObj">                       
                    <td>{{userDate.name}}</td> 
                    <td>{{patientData.dob}}</td> 
                </tr>                         
            </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/oVMpbjnE0XAuGHy83UKn?p=preview

Comment: To be clear; by the time it gets to Angular, it's not JSON; it's just JavaScript. JSON is just the string format used to send the data over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that in your plunker userDateObj is not array. You need to correct that as

```
<tr *ngFor="let userDate of userDateObj.userDate">
```

I have editted the plunker please find the update [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ORu5PohMzNlFSPmUQVbd?p=preview)

Comment: I am running the code from Microsoft Visual Code editor tool. But in the chrome debugger under my tbody tag i am getting this "<!--bindings={}-->". And rows are not getting shown.

Is the something i am missing???

Comment: My guess is because of variable given to ngFor(userDateObj) is not an array it is not displaying anything. Have a look at the plunker I provided

Answer (score 0):

To use *ngFor that object needs to be an array. If it's not an array then you can use a pipe to convert into an array.